# Convert .htaccess http authorization to nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, php-fpm

I need to convert the following .htaccess string to nginx config:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Can anyone help me?

I'm running nginx + php_fpm configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your PHP `location` block, or to your global `fastcgi_params` which it `include`s:

```
fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

Comment: I'm trying to move CMS Bitrix from apache to nginx.
I've already added that block to nginx, how ever CMS reports HTTP authentication is not set up correctly. May be I missed some other parameters in nginx.conf? Here is my "try" block:
https://gist.github.com/apetroff/5205137

Comment: You should have posted all of that originally.

Comment: Here it is, Michael:
https://gist.github.com/apetroff/5205264

Comment: I found that for me, I needed to add the following into my server's global fastcgi.conf: `fastcgi_param Authorization $http_authorization;` before restarting nginx